# How do I find a page with two specific links on it?

Tags: search, search-operators

I used to be able to do this in Google, but with the increasing dumbing down of Google this feature no longer works. e.g. I want science related news so I use Google:

> +link:www.physorg.com +link:www.sciencedaily.com

This used to find a bunch of pages with links to pages of science news. Now it doesn't work, and it won't work on Yahoo! either.

Another way to do this sort of research was using [Google Directory](http://www.google.com/dirhp) but it appears that Google have also pulled the plug on Directory search.

Is there another way to find a page with two links?

Answer (score 1):

How recently have you been able to do this? There is a fairly in-depth explanation of link: functionality [here](http://www.jlh-design.com/2007/06/why-link-doesnt-work-in-google/). There is also an explanation of why queries involving more than a singular link: operator [here](http://www.googleguide.com/advanced_operators.html#link).

Comment: Thanks, that's interesting. But I'm not so much concernced at understanding why it doesn't work as I am at finding an alternative way of doing this search.